# Turn a large list into a rowwise dataframe

Tags: r, performance, list, dataframe, data.table

I convert a large list to a dataframe using the structure command (I read the related posts in SO):

```
l <- list()
l[[1]]<-c("2048","0","25","0","453826","65101","1503497087","1503497031","4_1R")     

l[[2]]<-c("406","0","26","0","453826","65101","1503497087","1503497055","4_1R")      

l[[3]]<-c("407","0","27","0","453826","65101","1503497087","1503497083","4_1R")     


n <- length(l[[1]])
DF <- structure(l, row.names = c(NA, -n), class = "data.frame")
print(DF)
```

But the rows are arranged like columns. I could use transpose the dataframe:

```
library(data.table)
DF <- transpose(DF)
```

Which is fine,

however is there any option in "structure" to indicate I want a row-binding & row-ordered dataframe?

Comment: Try with `as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, l))`

Comment: You can get the same by just `as.data.frame(l, col.names = c('COL1','COL2','COL3'))`

Comment: @akrun I think they want `do.call(rbind, l)` or maybe `rbindlist(lapply(l, as.list))` from data.table.

Comment: You are all right, but for a large list (1GB) that takes a few seconds, I need a faster way. @Imo your rbindlist works, but I cannot make it out, I would expect rbindlist to row-bind a list.

Comment: Um, `transpose(setDT(l))` is as fast as you'll get, I'm pretty sure. If you want it faster, maybe try reading the data in in a better way..?

Answer (score 0):

If you unlist the list, it will give you a long vector, which you can then put into a matrix.  When putting the vector in a matrix, specifying `byrow=TRUE` will result in row-binding.  The matrix can be converted to a data frame.

```
> as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(l), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE))
    V1 V2 V3 V4     V5    V6         V7         V8   V9
1 2048  0 25  0 453826 65101 1503497087 1503497031 4_1R
2  406  0 26  0 453826 65101 1503497087 1503497055 4_1R
3  407  0 27  0 453826 65101 1503497087 1503497083 4_1R
```